# showing that encryption method is bijective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

A encryption method relates a letter Ω to letter $Δ\equiv aΩ + d$ $(mod 30)$ with $a, d\in {\Bbb N}$.
Each letter relates to a number: A = 01, B = 02, C = 03 ...

i. Show, that this encryption method with the key $(a, d)$ is bijective iff $gcd(a, 30) = 1$.
ii. How many posssible encriptions are there?

Comment: If $\gcd(a,30)\neq 1$, can you find two leeters which are sent to the same ? Conversely, if $\gcd(a,30)= 1$, can you find the inverse function ?
For the second question, just find the number of integers which satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** (i) In order to decrypt the message, the function needs to be invertable (hence a bijection). Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$. Which elements have an inverse? What property do they have?

(ii) Use the result from (i) to find all $a$ with $1 \leq a \leq 30$ and $\gcd(a,30)=1$.

Comment: So the inverse would be $(Ω-d)/a$ $(mod 30)$?

Comment: Essentially. The issue is with dividing by $a$. $a$ has to have an inverse in the group for that formula to work for everything.

Comment: How about $(aΩ + d)x ≡ 1 mod 30$?

Comment: Usually the inverse of $a$ is written $a^{-1}$. So you would have $\Omega = a^{-1}(\Delta-d) \pmod {30}$. But this only works for those $a$ that have an inverse in the first place.

Comment: The inverse of $a$ exists when $gcd(a, 30) = 1$?

Comment: Correct. That is why that condition is so important.